# When cold (10C), does turning on my water heater for 20min heat only part of the water heater to 60C or rise the temperature of the whole tank by 5C?

Tags: water-heater

I am wondering what would happen if I turn on my 120l water heater on for only 20min. Would I have 20l heated to 60C and the rest around 10C? or would the water heat pretty much evenly, and, after 20min, I would get 120l at around 15C? I am running with few solar panel at the moment and 50w standby losses would be a lot for me at the moment.

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: With most tanks there are two elements, but usually only one is on at a time.  The top half of the tank should warm up, but how much is hard to tell.  Most people who go off grid try to change their electric heating devices to gas/fuel/solar heating.

Comment: If you avoid turbulence a water storage tank can stratify into layers.  Thorsten chlupp has some good youtube videos of seasonal heat storage but he used a converted tanker truck in a vertical setup ( > 20' tall ) with an anti turbulence device on the water input.

Answer (score 3):

Neither, really. But the answer varies. Electric or gas? Gas heats from the bottom, mostly, so it mixes all the way up. But as warmer water acumulates at the top, it does not flow down until the water below is as warm as it is. Electric will heat the upper part (at or above the upper element level) until the upper element turns off and the lower one turns on.

Stratification is quite a strong effect here. The lower part of an electric tank will barely be affected by the upper element being on. And the circulation in a gas tank will start at the whole-tank scale with a cold tank, but reduce to the cooler annulus of water around the flue towards the bottom as the upper part gets hot.

Answer (score 0):

A tank-type water heater will heat the water equally.  It doesn't have the capability to know what water came in first and heat that first.

Natural convection in the tank will mix the water that it is more or less the same temperature.  There will be a slight difference in that the warmer water will rise to the top and displace cooler, but the difference won't be remarkable.

If you run your water heater for only 20 minutes, whatever amount of heat it can generate in that time will be equally distributed within the entire volume of the tank.

Comment: Stratification will be the dominant effect in the OP's situation -- remember that the incoming water is hitting the tank at the bottom thanks to the dip tube